# Unable to run pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I installed Spark on Windows, and I'm unable to start `pyspark`. When I type in `c:\Spark\bin\pyspark`, I get the following error:

> Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Spark\bin..\python\pyspark\shell.py", line 30, in import pyspark File "c:\Spark\python\pyspark__init__.py", line 44, in from pyspark.context import SparkContext File "c:\Spark\python\pyspark\context.py", line 36, in from pyspark.java_gateway import launch_gateway File "c:\Spark\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 31, in from py4j.java_gateway import java_import, JavaGateway, GatewayClient File "", line 961, in _find_and_load File "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 646, in _load_unlocked File "", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible File "c:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 18, in File "C:\Users\Eigenaar\Anaconda3\lib\pydoc.py", line 62, in import pkgutil File "C:\Users\Eigenaar\Anaconda3\lib\pkgutil.py", line 22, in ModuleInfo = namedtuple('ModuleInfo', 'module_finder name ispkg') File "c:\Spark\python\pyspark\serializers.py", line 393, in namedtuple cls = _old_namedtuple(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'verbose', 'rename', and 'module'

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I can name a couple of things that you are doing wrong -- _(1)_ you formatted your log entries as "blockquote" (used for quoting plain text e.g. documentation) instead of "code sample"; _(2)_ you did not mention the version of Spark you have installed: _(3)_ you did not even try to Google `spark TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments` which would have shown https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19019 as the top answer.

Comment: Please try to keep the line endings in your traceback, to make it remotely readable.

Answer (score 32):

Spark 2.1.0 doesn't support python 3.6.0.
To solve this change your python version in anaconda environment.
Run following command in your anaconda env

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
activate py35
```

Answer (score 23):

Spark <= 2.1.0 is not compatible with Python 3.6. See [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19019), which also claims that this will be fixed with the upcoming Spark release.

Comment: I have the same issue! I didn't know before that Spark 2.1.0 is not compatible with Python 3.6.

Comment: Is Spark-2.2.0 compatible with Python-3.6. Any idea ?

Comment: @JKC According to the linked issue, 2.2.0 should work just fine and 2.1.1 as well.

Comment: I faced same issue with python3.6. Changed PYSPARK_PYTHON to point to python3.5 or using python3.5 instead of 3.6 fixed it. PYSPARK_PYTHON is a better approach imho

Answer (score 11):

I resolved this issue using one change in the pythons script.

I have place below piece of code in python script named serializers.py , location is `c:\your-installation-dir\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop-2.7\python\pyspark\` and below line to be replace at Line number 381.

```
cls = _old_namedtuple(*args, **kwargs, verbose=False, rename=False, module=None)
```

**And then run pyspark into your command line this will work..**

Comment: This solves the problem, just a little more explanation below, feel free to edit in this information to complete your answer.

Comment: This solved the initial problem, but I believe the dependencies are far more intricate, this only fixed the first of many collisions.

Comment: Worked like magic.. Thanks a ton.. Was struggling for a couple of days with this issue

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to extend on Indrajeet's answer, since he mentioned line numbers instead of the exact location of the code. Please see this in addition to his answer for further clarification.

## cls = _old_namedtuple(*args, **kwargs) 
 is the line that was changed being referred in his answer

```
def _hijack_namedtuple():
""" Hack namedtuple() to make it picklable """
# hijack only one time
if hasattr(collections.namedtuple, "__hijack"):
    return

global _old_namedtuple  # or it will put in closure

def _copy_func(f):
    return types.FunctionType(f.__code__, f.__globals__, f.__name__,
                              f.__defaults__, f.__closure__)

_old_namedtuple = _copy_func(collections.namedtuple)

def namedtuple(*args, **kwargs):
    # cls = _old_namedtuple(*args, **kwargs)
    cls = _old_namedtuple(*args, **kwargs, verbose=False, rename=False, module=None)
    return _hack_namedtuple(cls)
```

!!! EDIT 6th Mar 2017!!
This did fix the original issue, but I don't think this will make spark 2.1 compatible with 3.6 yet, there were more collisions further down. As a result I used conda to create a python 35 virtual environment and it worked like a charm.

(Windows, assuming you have env variables in place)

```
>conda create -n py35 python=3.5
>activate py35 
>pyspark
```

Comment: Hi @D.S. I created a new environment for python=3.5 as you have suggested but when I entered pyspark, I am getting the error "pyspark is not recognised as an internal or external command" even though I have setup spark_home and pythonpath environment variables properly. Any inputs on how to resolve this ?

Comment: This was a while back, but I realized its not worth the effort to do this on a windows box, so I set up virtualbox with a ubuntu image and my work moved much quicker. I know this doesn't fix your immediate issue but if you make the switch you'll save a lot more time fighting such annoying conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

The Possible Issues faced when running Spark on Windows is, of not giving proper Path or by using Python 3.x to run Spark.

So,

1. Do check Path Given for spark i.e /usr/local/spark Proper or Not.
2. Do set Python Path to Python 2.x (remove Python 3.x).