# Cannot run pyspark in MAC after SPARK installation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I recently installed SPARK in my MAC computer using the following command:

```
brew install apache-spark
```

Now I tried to run 
pyspark but it is showing me the following error.

```
pyspark

Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 30, in <module>
 import pyspark
File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/pyspark/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/pyspark/context.py", line 36, in <module>
   from pyspark.java_gateway import launch_gateway
File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 31, in <module>
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import, JavaGateway, GatewayClient
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 18, in <module>
 File "/Users/hellmaster/anaconda/lib/python3.6/pydoc.py", line 62, in <module>
```

```
    import pkgutil
 File "/Users/hellmaster/anaconda/lib/python3.6/pkgutil.py", line 22, in <module>
    ModuleInfo = namedtuple('ModuleInfo', 'module_finder name ispkg')
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 393, in namedtuple
 cls = _old_namedtuple(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'verbose', 'rename', and 'module'
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is because Spark 2.1.0 is incompatible with Python 3.6.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349980/unable-to-run-pyspark).